# Spring Batch on application server: JobExecution not found on afterJob listener

Tags: spring-batch, application-server

I'm new to Spring batch and Spring in general. I'm developing a batch job that will run on WebSphere Application Server. So far I've just built a skeleton with some dummy step. I also have a listener for updating some Oracle DB tables at the end of the job. Here's part of my appContext:

```
<batch:job id="spedizioneJob" restartable="true" parent="bankitJob">
        <batch:step id="verifyInputStep" next="technicalPropertiesEnforcementStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="verifyInput" />
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step id="technicalPropertiesEnforcementStep" next="protocolAndProbatoryStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="technicalPropertiesEnforcement" />
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step id="protocolAndProbatoryStep" next="exdiSendingStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="protocolAndProbatory" />
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step id="exdiSendingStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="exdiSending" />
        </batch:step>
        <batch:listeners merge="true">
            <batch:listener ref="spedizioneJobListener" />
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:job>
```

Here's the beginning afterJob snippet:

```
public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

    // get params
    String iref = jobExecution.getJobParameters().getString("APPL_REQ_ID");
    SpedizioneInput spInput=(SpedizioneInput)jobExecution.getExecutionContext().get("input");
```

What's strange, in some of my test run (local test environment on Rational Application Developer, but same happens on a server istance of WAS), typically not the first, the jobExecution is not found and I got this exception:

```
[03/10/14 12.47.48:505 CEST] 0000003a AbstractJob   E org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob execute Encountered fatal error executing job
                                 org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.NoSuchObjectException: Invalid JobExecution, ID 224 not found.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.updateJobExecution(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:218)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at $Proxy36.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.updateStatus(AbstractJob.java:416)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:299)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
```

I don't know if this has something to do with the way I run the job.... I configured such a kind of launcher:

```
<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="taskExecutor">
        <bean class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

And I launch my job from a Session EJB whi gets invoket by a Servlet. Here's the EJB code while launching:

```
try {
            System.out.println("Before launching spedizione job");
            JobExecution jexec=jobLauncher.run(job, jpb.toJobParameters());
            System.out.println("After launching spedizione job "+jexec.getJobConfigurationName()+" status "+jexec.getStatus().toString());
```

My log confirms this is issueing an async call to the job as expected, but I suspect the session bean transaction may sometimes not commit before the job gets on the afterJob method of the listener...

Thanks in advance for your possible reply

Comment: Can you add some insight into the way you have transactions configured?

Comment: Hi.For what concerns the Session Bean that is invoking the jobLauncher.run, I did not configure anything in particular, so transactions are container managed and default should be REQUIRED, I can check against websphere documentation. For what concerns the spring batch job configuration, I just specified  org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager as transaction manager for the job repository. 
The dataSource used for handling the jobRepository is configured in the WebSphere Application Server using an Oracle XA JDBC provider

Comment: Why are you using the `ResourcelessTransactionManager`?  The error above is probably due to the combination of launching the batch job within the scope of a transaction (in the EJB) and not using transactions within Spring Batch (by way of using the `ResourcelessTransactionManager`.  The job is trying to update a record in the repository but the session bean hans't committed it's transaction yet so it isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Michael, the problem was the transaction manager I was usign. As i switched to WebSphereUowTransactionManager I solved my issue.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/WebSphereUowTransactionManager.html